# How can I reduce space at top of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I want to locate my `algorithm` at the bottom of two-column paper as compact as possible.  On top of the algorithm I see an empty space line, is it possible to remove it, or decrease the space?

my code:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for\\ IEEE Computer Society Journals}
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2015}%
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file
\lipsum*[100]

\begin{algorithm}[!bp]
    \caption{The submitJob Function}
    \label{algo-cost}  % \hspace*{\algorithmicindent}
    \vspace*{0.5mm}
    \hspace*{0.45cm} \textbf{Input:} {\(x_{s}, x_{n}\)} \\
    \hspace*{0.45cm} \textbf{Output:} {Returns calculated cost}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State{}\(x \gets \phi[p_{n}]\)
        \State{}\(y \gets \phi[d_{n}]\)
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

output (bottom left corner of the page):

[image]

Here as you can see there is an empty space on top of the algorithm. When I use `\vspace*{-2mm}` it did not help. In some cases the space is two lines.

Comment: You have not provided an example that anyone can run. space around floats is specified by the document class which you omitted from the posted code for some reason?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add `\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}` and `\usepackage{float}` to top of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This space is governed by `\textfloatsep`, as can be seen from the general [`layouts` package/documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/layouts) (section **6.2 Detailed float layout**):

[image]

`\textfloatsep` defines the typical space or `sep`aration between the `text` and a top/bottom `float` (other, "`in`ternal" floats have a `sep`aration defined by `\intextsep`). You'll find the following definition of `\textfloatsep` within [`IEEEtran.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls):

```
\textfloatsep 1.55\baselineskip plus  0.2\baselineskip minus  0.4\baselineskip
```

This is quite large (`1.55\baselineskip`), for whatever reason. You can adjust this to suit your needs somewhere in the preamble. Using a smaller primary length/gap like

```
\textfloatsep = 1\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.4\baselineskip
```

results in a slightly smaller gap (because there's still a small stretch/shrink; the `=` is optional):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmicx}

\textfloatsep = 1\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.4\baselineskip

\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for\\ IEEE Computer Society Journals}
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2015}%
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file
\lipsum*[100]

\begin{algorithm}[!bp]
  \caption{The submitJob Function}
  \vspace*{0.5mm}
  \hspace*{0.45cm} \textbf{Input:} {\(x_{s}, x_{n}\)} \\
  \hspace*{0.45cm} \textbf{Output:} {Returns calculated cost}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State{}\(x \gets \phi[p_{n}]\)
    \State{}\(y \gets \phi[d_{n}]\)
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Adjust it to suit your needs, but know that this is something that is set globally. Also, if this is for a journal submission, such changes are often overridden by the publisher.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks for it

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the place indicator is `[bp!]` so the compiler will arrange things before hand and isn't able to apply spacing tools after, because the positions of the environments in the code aren't the same as in the output. For example just changing the placeholder to `[h]` produces the following output:

[image: Output Algorithm package]

It doesn't have the double spacing like before. And it also allows `\vspace{}` to function as expected because the placing of the figure relative to the text is unambiguous.

```
%Example of uncomfortably narrow spacing

\lipsum*[100]
\vspace{-0.2cm} %Now it works as expected
\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \caption{The submitJob Function}
    \label{algo-cost}  % \hspace*{\algorithmicindent}
    \vspace*{0.5mm}
    \hspace*{0.45cm} \textbf{Input:} {\(x_{s}, x_{n}\)} \\
    \hspace*{0.45cm} \textbf{Output:} {Returns calculated cost}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State{}\(x \gets \phi[p_{n}]\)
        \State{}\(y \gets \phi[d_{n}]\)
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\vspace{-0.2cm} %Text afterwards also works as expected
\lipsum
```

Output: [image: algorithm spacing corrected]

Comment: but using `[h]` doee not place the algorithm at bottom of the page, which I wanted